# Using OpenXML SDK via C++/CLI

Tags: .net, sdk, c++-cli, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to use the OpenXML SDK 2.5 via C++/CLI. Using the example code at the bottom of this MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478153.aspx) works correctly when compiled with C# - I can open the created file successfully in Excel 2007.

The MSDN example code I translated to C++/CLI as follows:

```
void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(String^ filepath)
{
    // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
    // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
    SpreadsheetDocument^ spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument::Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType::Workbook);

    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    WorkbookPart^ workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument->AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookpart->Workbook = gcnew Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    WorksheetPart^ worksheetPart = workbookpart->AddNewPart<WorksheetPart^>();
    worksheetPart->Worksheet = gcnew Worksheet(gcnew SheetData());

    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    Sheets^ sheets = spreadsheetDocument->WorkbookPart->Workbook->AppendChild<Sheets^>(gcnew Sheets());

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet^ sheet = gcnew Sheet();
    sheet->Id = spreadsheetDocument->WorkbookPart->GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);
    sheet->SheetId = 1;
    sheet->Name = L"mySheet";
    sheets->Append(sheet);

    workbookpart->Workbook->Save();

    // Close the document.
    spreadsheetDocument->Close();
}
```

The code compiles, but the file created is not complete. Excel 2007 complains about a corrupt file. Upon examining the contents of the xlsx file it looks like the details of the "mySheet"-sheet class does not get written to disk. What am I missing in the C++/CLI code that this is not working correctly?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 targeting .Net Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI can not instantiate classes like you can do it in C#, multiple in one time. And sometimes you must use AppendChild and not just Append method but I don't know why

```
   // *** same code like you

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    WorksheetPart^ worksheetPart = workbookpart->AddNewPart<WorksheetPart^>();
    SheetData^ sheetData = gcnew SheetData();
    worksheetPart->Worksheet = gcnew Worksheet();
    worksheetPart->Worksheet->AppendChild(sheetData);

    // same code like you 

    sheets->AppendChild(sheet);  // *->AppendChild not just *->Append

    workbookpart->Workbook->Save();

    // Close the document.
    spreadsheetDocument->Close();
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be great. Also highlighting the changes or limiting the post to the required changes would be a benefit.

Comment: C++/CLI can not instantiate classes like you can do it in C#, multiple in one time. And sometimes you must use AppendChild and not just Append method but right now I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It would be great if you could edit your answer and add your explanation as an introduction to your solution. Maybe you also want to revise the line containing the fixed file path (`C:\\xxx\\ExcelDoc.xlsx`).